# Index Match Function: iterate over multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Sory for my initial post where I did not provided a detailed description of what I want to do.

I want to get the value of a cell when it matches two criteria. One criteria is a fix cell, while the second one I need to iterate it.

**Example:**

`Cells(2,1) = A` (It matches "Name" and `Criteria2 (Cells(1,6))`, for `Cells(3,1)` I want to apply the same but with `Criteria2 (Cells(2,6))` and so on.

My alternative is to filter Range Criteria 1 (which I already did) and then get all the values available, but I have to apply the same process for 3 different sets and I have a feeling that I can have a better approach with match/Index.

Below you can find my excel file, code and the output.

[image]

Here is the output of my code:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
Sub match_index()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long
i = 2

Dim criteria1 As String
criteria1 = ws.Cells(1, 4).Value
Dim criteria2 As String
criteria2 = ws.Cells(1, 6).Value

Dim criteria_range1 As Range
Set criteria_range1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 8), ws.Cells(14, 8))
Dim criteria_range2 As Range
Set criteria_range2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 9), ws.Cells(14, 9))


With Application
While i < 8
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = .Index(criteria_range2, _
        .Match(criteria1, criteria_range1, 0), _
        .Match(ws.Cells(i, 6).Value, criteria_range2, 0), 1)
        i = i + 1
Wend
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you care to explain what you're doing and ask a question?

Comment: sorry @SJR. I edi my post.

Comment: with excel formula it would like this: {=INDEX(criteria_range2, match(criteria1&criteria2, criteria_range1&criteria_range2))}, but I don't get how it can be done with VBA...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. I used If statement with Like function:

```
x = 2
y = 1
For i = 2 To 14
    criteria2 = ws.Cells(y, 6).Value
    If criteria1 Like ws.Cells(i, 8).Value And criteria2 Like ws.Cells(i, 9).Value Then
        ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
        y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```